# problems compiling a function with a trait Add in Rust

Tags: functions, rust

I'm trying to write a generic function summ in rust - but to no avail. Could someone please elucidate the problem?

```
fn summ<T:Add>(a:T,b:T)->T  {
    a+b
}
```

Comment: recommended reading: **[Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Add`'s `add` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html) does not return `Self` - it returns `Self::Output`. This allows the addition to return a different type than the addends. The return type of `summ` should reflect that:

```
fn summ<T: Add>(a: T, b: T) -> T::Output  {
    a + b
}
```

Comment: thanx a lot - it works like a charm .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Rust, but I'm assuming that since there are no constraints on `T`, there's no way to know that it even *has* a `+` operator. You should probably constrain `T` to implement `std::ops::Add`.

Comment: well good sugestion - but not necessary in my case - thanx.